# How do I use a for loop in Matlab to select rows where the values are different between two columns?

Tags: matlab

Here is my data from the Matlab output;

```
      a        Aerobic                 Anaerobic
   'Ex_Cl'  -0.00775597205802433    -0.00775597205802011
   'Ex_Sulfate' -0.100000000000000  -0.100000000000000
   'Ex_Cu2+'    -0.00517064803868288    -0.00517064803868008
   'Ex_Mg'  -0.0129249011312688 -0.0129249011312618
   'Ex_Ca2+'    -0.00775597205802433    -0.00775597205802011
   'Ex_NH3' 0   4.24088035850684
   'Ex_H2O' -10 -10
   'Ex_Biomass' 1.71896543839192    1.71896543839098
   'Ex_Butyrate'    0   0
```

There are 184  rows altogether. The col names are a, Aerobic and Anaerobic respectively.

I am trying to create a for loop to just select the metabolites which are different between the aerobic and anaerobic, and also are only positive too.

The table was formed from d=table(a, Aerobic, Anaerobic).
Here is my code for trying to just get a new table which contains only the positive values which are different aerobic and anaerobic.

```
    j=1
    for i=1 : height (d)
         if (b(i) ~= c(i))
         difExc(j, 1:3) = d(i, 1:3)
         j=j+1
         else
         continue;
         end
    end
```

And then I would like to create a new table

```
      difExc=table(a, Aerobic, Anaerobic)
```

I've got the different bit,  but I am not sure how to adjust the code to also say select only those which are positive and different between aerobic and anaerobic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank-you

Comment: The `if` in the `for`-loop is not closed by an `end`, that's where the error comes from.

Comment: @Patrick Happel Thank-you

Answer (score 1):

You can use logical indexing to find the values that are different. This is the data I used

```
 a = [...
   "Ex_Cl" 
   "Ex_Sulfate"
   "Ex_Cu2+"  
   "Ex_Mg"
   "Ex_Ca2+"    
   "Ex_NH3" 
   "Ex_H2O" 
   "Ex_Biomass" 
   "Ex_Butyrate"];   
Aerobic = [ ...
    -0.00775597205802433
    -0.100000000000000  
    -0.00517064803868288
    -0.0129249011312688
    -0.00775597205802433    
    0
    -10 
    1.71896543839192    
    0];   
Anaerobic = [ ...
    -0.00775597205802011
    -0.100000000000000
    -0.00517064803868008    
    -0.0129249011312618
    -0.00775597205802011
    4.24088035850684
    -10
    1.71896543839098
    0];
```

And this is finding the differences:

```
different = Aerobic ~= Anaerobic;

T = table(a(different), Aerobic(different), Anaerobic(different))
```

Result

```
T =

  6×3 table

        Var1           Var2          Var3   
    ____________    __________    __________

    "Ex_Cl"          -0.007756     -0.007756
    "Ex_Cu2+"       -0.0051706    -0.0051706
    "Ex_Mg"          -0.012925     -0.012925
    "Ex_Ca2+"        -0.007756     -0.007756
    "Ex_NH3"                 0        4.2409
    "Ex_Biomass"         1.719         1.719
```